# netbeans giving error when i tried to deploy servlet application?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, servlets, netbeans6.7

i am using netbeans 6.7.1 and apache tomcat server 7.0 but when in tried to deploy my servlet application it gives following errors

```
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FDOCUME%7E1%2FBadr%2FLOCALS%7E1%2FTemp%2Fcontext6286056025186380410.xml&path=/iEHR
http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FDOCUME%7E1%2FBadr%2FLOCALS%7E1%2FTemp%2Fcontext6286056025186380410.xml&path=/iEHR
D:\CWM\iEHR System\iEHR\nbproject\build-impl.xml:584: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 36 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Netbeans 6.7.1 has not supported Tomcat 7.0 yet, even Netbeans 6.9 or 6.9.1. Try Tomcat 6.0 or 5.0. I see Eclipse Helios has already support Tomcat 7.0 in its server list.